# Missing New Task and Log a Call button in Lightning

Tags: lightning-experience, activities

I found that New Task, Log a Call buttons are missing from the activity in Lightning experience. I did added them to Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions section of the page layout. And also we have record types for Task object.

Am I missing anything else?

[image]

Pagelayout:

[image]

Comment: Which object are you working here ? In my org I see all these actions .

Comment: Account and contact objects and also checked with custom object, same behaviour

Comment: Thats weird that your org does not have them ? Did you try editing via app builder and add the acitivities component ?

Comment: I went to the app builder and then went to page layout and added the buttons to Mobile and Lightning section.

Comment: I guess nothing to do with Spring 18 release.

Comment: Noticed that, if we have record types associated in Task object, then New Task button will not appear. What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed that, if we have record types on task object, the standard buttons will not show up in the Activity publisher. We may have to create Quick Actions to create Tasks. If we create quick actions, then they will show up in the Activity tab automatically.[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000356861&type=1

check out this article it fixed my issue.

"Open any record.
Click the gear icon and click Edit Page.
Click the affected related list component.
At the right panel, select Show list view action bar.
Click Save."

Answer (score -2):

Make sure to perform the below steps to get the other actions displayed under the lightning Activities tab:

Switch to classic > Object (Impacted) > Page Layouts > Add buttons/actions to Lightning and mobile section.

Reference: https://www.simplysfdc.com/2018/08/salesforce-lightning-log-call-button.html

Comment: Though the link might answer the question, it's recommended to give brief answer here