# Opportunity log a call missing in lightning

Tags: lightning, administration

I am another person missing log a call, and I want to add it in the oppportunity.

this is slightly different to some of already questions in stackexchange such as

- His action at least shows in the panel, I dont have this option, but I do have it in classic [Missing New Task and Log a Call button in Lightning](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/204384/missing-new-task-and-log-a-call-button-in-lightning)

I can see that a lot of people is/was having the same issue as me, but I decided to create this as mine seems a little bit different, I have follow Salesforce knowledge base article: [Knowledge based article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000247872&type=1)

However, I dont have the global action log a call, is not this supposed to be an standard action?

[image: Current production global actions]

This is my current set up in the opportunity layout
[image: Quick Actions]

And [image: Mobile Actions]

This is how it displays in Classic where the log a call is present:

[image]

This is in lightning
[image: Lightning view that miss the call button]

Comment: Forgot to mention, I dont have record types in Task and Events

Comment: The one in Classic Activity History is a standard button. In addition to that it also exists as an Action in Global Action. If you don't have that in the Global Action, you may like to verify if that was deleted at any point of time.

Comment: @JayantDas thank you I couldnt see anything been deleted in audit trail, and i am the only admin. But, are you saying that if there was a global action it will show up in the Activity tab? I thought the global action will show somewhere else, I pointed out, as i find it bizard that I dont have that in global action

Comment: If it was in global action and that there was a record type assigned (per knowledge article), then it would show up (I verified that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally was able to get it, this was missing from the Global Actions, it is quite weird as this was never deleted, it was just missing.

I get the metadata from a dev org, and deploy it via ant

Package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>LogACall</members>
        <name>QuickAction</name>
    </types>
    <version>43.0</version>
</Package>
```

In the folder quickActions, I had a file LogACall.quickAction

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<QuickAction xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <optionsCreateFeedItem>true</optionsCreateFeedItem>
    <quickActionLayout>
        <layoutSectionStyle>TwoColumnsLeftToRight</layoutSectionStyle>
        <quickActionLayoutColumns>
            <quickActionLayoutItems>
                <emptySpace>false</emptySpace>
                <field>Subject</field>
                <uiBehavior>Edit</uiBehavior>
            </quickActionLayoutItems>
            <quickActionLayoutItems>
                <emptySpace>false</emptySpace>
                <field>WhoId</field>
                <uiBehavior>Edit</uiBehavior>
            </quickActionLayoutItems>
        </quickActionLayoutColumns>
        <quickActionLayoutColumns>
            <quickActionLayoutItems>
                <emptySpace>false</emptySpace>
                <field>Description</field>
                <uiBehavior>Edit</uiBehavior>
            </quickActionLayoutItems>
            <quickActionLayoutItems>
                <emptySpace>false</emptySpace>
                <field>WhatId</field>
                <uiBehavior>Edit</uiBehavior>
            </quickActionLayoutItems>
        </quickActionLayoutColumns>
    </quickActionLayout>
    <standardLabel>LogACall</standardLabel>
    <targetObject>Task</targetObject>
    <type>LogACall</type>
</QuickAction>
```

Then I was able to added into Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions