# Log a Call Button on Lightning

Tags: lightning, permissions, profile, button, activities

I cannot get the log a call tab to appear on the lightning page. I am just using the standard activity component. It seems to apply to all objects, but for now we can just focus on opportunities.

I've got it narrowed down to an issue with profiles. With one profile, the users can log a call, create a new task, and create a new event. With another, the only option is New Event.

Sharing settings for activities are set to private. I have adjusted all the object permissions to mirror each other. "Edit Tasks" and "Edit Events" are both checked true on the system permissions. I have the log a call button available on the global actions layout, but I have also tried overwriting the buttons on the page layout.

What could I possibly be missing?

Comment: Did you look into this? https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000247872&type=1

Comment: I did, sorry for excluding that. We have different record types and I have selected one of the record types. There isn't a way to exclude task record types from an opportunity, is there?

Comment: Does the profile where they are not able to see log a call have the Edit Tasks permission checked?

Comment: Yes.. They have both Edit Tasks and Edit Events.

Comment: This might help https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/204384/missing-new-task-and-log-a-call-button-in-lightning

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried creating a global action. I tried defaulting the page layout to the global actions and then tried explictly adding the quick action. Nothing worked. I', thinking I may just delete the profile and clone another one. I'm at my wits end.

Comment: does `log a call` button show in classic for the same profile?

Comment: It does not, @ItaiShmida - I thin the problem is that I pulled that profile from a sandbox. It was created and pushed in a change set, which seems to not keep the same settings. But still, I should be able to go through and actually edit the profile to match the settings of another profile that DOES work, right?

Comment: if you have the same problem in classic - it should be a permissions issue. try creating this profile by yourself. if it is hard to copy all properties, you can use https://perm-comparator.herokuapp.com/ - it will help you compare the profiles