# Add "New Task" tab to in activities timeline

Tags: lightning, tasks, activity

Some of my users are unable to see this tab under the activities timeline. I tried a solution where I would change the record type to a custom record type, but that makes it disappear from my view (System Admin profile).[image]

Answer (score 0):

If we have any custom record type on the Activities(Event or Task), we need to [create a global action](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.creating_global_actions.htm&type=5) and define the record type on it and add it to the layout.

In my developer org, I have created a record type for Event object and so create Event button disappeared from the activities. After I created a global action and specified the record type and added it to the layout, it again appeared.

See related posts :

https://www.simplysfdc.com/2018/08/salesforce-lightning-log-call-button.html

[Missing New Task and Log a Call button in Lightning](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/204384/missing-new-task-and-log-a-call-button-in-lightning)

Comment: There's already a New Task global action with the --Master-- record type selected. If I select the custom record type, then it disappears from my view as well.